# Imap port forwarding through an intermediary

Tags: imap, portforwarding

I have 2 servers. An isolated application server (PHP) that can not access the GMAIL IMAP server (imap.gmail.com:993). A second server on the internal network that can acesss. The application server and the second server communicate well. I would like to call the Gmail IMAP from the application server via the second server.

I tested Squid, not working. because Squid is an HTTP proxy. HTTP is NOT pop3, smtp, imap. So I tried imap over ssh with the following command:

`ssh -N -L 1234:imap.gmail.com:993-L user@mysecondhost`

But When I test with my PHP code :

`$connect_to = '{localhost:1234/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$user = 'mygmailaccord@gmail.com';
$password = 'mypassword';`

`$connection = imap_open($connect_to, $user, $password)
  or die("Can't connect to '$connect_to': " . imap_last_error());
echo  "ok";
imap_close($connection);`

The tunnel not working. Any idea how I can call the Gmail imap service ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The tunnel not working..."  - the specific error messages you get might be helpful to track down the problem.

Comment: Connexion Timeout when I call the imap server